# Selecting several rows from mysql with specified total sum of one column

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

Table **item_info**:

```
ID | Name       | Price
---+------------+-------
1  | Item one   | 0.2
2  | Item two   | 0.3
3  | Item three | 0.1
4  | Item four  | 0.6
```

Table **item_list**:

```
ID | item_id | available
---+---------+----------
1  |       1 | 1
2  |       3 | 1
3  |       2 | 1
4  |       1 | 1
5  |       4 | 1
etc..
```

I need to select any number of rows from table **item_list** which is joined with table **item_info** in total sum of column **Price** from table **item_info** = 0.6 $

for example it can select 3 rows with **item_list.item_id** = 1,2,3 or one row with **item_list.item_id** 4 - no matter but in result it should be sum not more than 0.6$

also I need to select item_list.available=1 items only and than mark them as unavailable later

I tried a few requests, but nothing really usable

I need something like

```
select item_list.ID, item_info.Name 
from item_list
inner join item_info on item_info.ID=item_list.item_id
where item_list.available = 1  
  and total sum of rows item_info.price <= 0.6
```

I tried to use variables

```
select @sum:=0;
select *,@sum:=@sum+price as total_sum from (
  select item_list.ID,item_info.price from item_list
    inner join item_info on item_info.ID=item_list.item_id
    where item_list.available=1 
  order by price asc
) s
having total_sum<=0.6
```

but it not the best way, is selects items from cheapest to most expensive, also it reads full table before..not the best way to solve this problem as I think

Comment: What exactly did you try to do and what errors / problems did you encounter?

Comment: user gives me 0.6$ and I need to give him any random items for that price

Comment: You cannot do this with a simple query

Comment: it can be complex query with variables or any other... I tried, but after 6 hours did not found any suitable results

Comment: You can do it on PHP side. The idea is next: user give you some money `$total`, you fetch items `WHERE price < $total`, then you get first (or random) element from result array. subtract `$money = $total - $itemPrice`, then find in result array the element with Item price `<= $money` and etc.

Comment: I already tried such algo...but there were a small hope, that it can be better way

Answer (score 0):

The logic is relatively simple, however, it cannot be implemented in a single query, no matter how complex it gets. Obviously, you can use a stored procedure in mysql to implement the logic, or you you can use php as well.

1. Count the items, those price is less than or equal to your limit. If this is 0, then either you have no qualifying items or your list is ready - see step 3 below.
2. Retrieve 1 random item with its price, which price is less than or equal to your limit by generating a random whole number between 0 and count-1 and using it in a limit statement:

   `select itemid, price from table order by itemid limit randomnumber, 1`
3. Deduct the price from the limit. If your remaining limit is 0, then you have your list. If not, then repeat the above steps with your remaining limit becoming your new limit. If you do not want to include the same item twice in the list, then exclude the itemids you have in your list when repeating the above steps by adding a not in() to the where clause.

Comment: I tried to do in a such way previously, but thought it's not the best way...
but looking for all responces - maybe such way is the best one. The only one thing i'm worrying about is many queries, which can be potentially genereted by this algo... if I select a few rows, but it''s sum will be lower I will need to make 2nd query and mb 3rd...